# AsyncTask and JSON, onSuccess doesn't return anything

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm here with another question. I post you the code from my AsyncTask function to get values from a JSONObject (webservice). My problem is that I have a List and I fill this list with the data from the json in the onSuccess method, but later, in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask, "result" is null.

```
private class getCategories extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Category>> {

        private int num_cat_subcat; // category count

        @Override
        protected List<Category> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get(arg0[0], null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                public void onSuccess(JSONObject data) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject response = data.getJSONObject("response");
                        JSONArray categories = response
                                .getJSONArray("categories");

                        // elements count
                        num_cat_subcat = categories.length();

                        for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject item = (JSONObject) categories
                                    .getJSONObject(i);

                            if (item.getString("id").equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    "4d4b7105d754a06376d81259")) {
                                JSONArray subcategories = item
                                        .getJSONArray("categories");

                                // Category --> id, name, pluralName, shortName,
                                // icon_prefix, icon_suffix, primary, parentId
                                Category newItem = new Category(item
                                        .getString("id"), item
                                        .getString("name"), item
                                        .getString("pluralName"), item
                                        .getString("shortName"), null, null,
                                        null);
                                listCategories.add(newItem);
                                newItem = null;

                                if (subcategories.length() > 0) {
                                    // Si tiene subcategorias las contamos.
                                    num_cat_subcat += subcategories.length();

                                    for (int j = 0; j < subcategories.length(); j++) {
                                        JSONObject subitem = (JSONObject) subcategories
                                                .getJSONObject(j);

                                        Category newSubItem = new Category(
                                                subitem.getString("id"),
                                                subitem.getString("name"),
                                                subitem.getString("pluralName"),
                                                subitem.getString("shortName"),
                                                null, null, item
                                                        .getString("id"));
                                        listCategories.add(newSubItem);
                                        newSubItem = null;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {

                }
            });
            return listCategories;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Category> result) {
            Log.i("result", result.toString());

            for (int k = 0; k < result.size(); k++) {
                ALLOFTHEM += result.get(k).getId();
                if (k < result.size() - 1) {
                    ALLOFTHEM += ",";
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: do you see the data you want on ur `ListView`.DOes your debug monitor take you inside `onPostExecute`

Comment: is there any exception printed?

Comment: i think u should put some Log msgs to check at what point your code is working.

Comment: are u using loopj api?

Comment: It shows me a log in logcat when enter the onPostExecute. But inside the onSuccess listCategories have the data, and outside, on onPostExecute result it is shows as [] in the logcat

Answer (score 3):

if you are using [loopj android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) then no need to use `AsyncTask` for getting data from server `doInBackground` and updating UI in onPostExecute because `onSuccess` method always execute on UI Thread after background computation. just do it without AsyncTask as :

```
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
 client.get("Pass Url Here", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(JSONObject data) {
          // update your ListView here
      }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);

    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know that

Comment: i've got a similar problem! im doing a async login through AsyncTask using ρяσѕρєя K way, but its not working and im getting a nullPointerException. if i do the login in the main thread it works fine. why? i am using loopj library!

Answer (score 2):

`onPostExecuted` is called when the `doInBackground` runs out its execution. If the get method of `AsyncHttpClient` is not a blocking method, `onPostExecuted` is called before `onSuccess` parses the result

Comment: why is this an answer and not a comment?

Comment: Why should it be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecuted is called before onSuccess parses the result, So try display something in your loop or debug that code.

```
    Log.e("Test", item.getString("id"));//inside for Loop
```

And Also use this before your for loop

```
   listCategories = new List<Category>();
```

Hopes it help.

Comment: It shows me a log in logcat when enter the onPostExecute. But inside the onSuccess listCategories have the data, and outside, on onPostExecute result it is shows as [] in the logcat