# GZipped content in http response of GET request using async-http-library for Android

Tags: android, android-async-http

I'm trying to access Google's geocode API using [Android-Async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library in my app. [Here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US%7Cpostal_code:65565%7Clocality:Steelville%7Cadministrative_area:Missouri&sensor=false) is my request and below is response:

���������������UMo�0��WX>Ӫ  i{���UJ�$�J�
mߔ%�===�������B��R��}���#�4�.�d�{��$�b��D��V<��<�����w*y�q���y5����o�   �����

Here is success callback method of AsyncHttpResponseHandler.

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        try {
            String response = new String(responseBody);
            //String response = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8"); //this is also giving junk reponse
            Log.v("SUCCESS RESPONSE", response);
            networkCallback.onSuccess(response);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Why am i getting the response as junk? How do I get proper response?

Comment: What is the type of response? is it JSON or String?. May be your converting JSON Response as String.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar : Google's geocode API can return the response in json and xml formats. I have specified that in my request url which is json.

Comment: Yes Then you need to receive it as JSON right? like this `@Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // If the response is JSONObject
            }`

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar : There is no such that method in Android-async-http library. It just gives the http response in byte array format. So I'm converting byte array to string and then json object

Comment: What is the character encoding according to the HTTP header?

Comment: Is perhaps gzip enabled?

Comment: May be i am wrong but please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16790526/4596556) and [here](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/ResponseHandlerInterface.html)

Comment: @BartFriederichs : Yes. It is enabled. Do I need to change it? If so, How do I change it?

Comment: You can change it in your request headers, or enable gzip in your receiving side. Refer to the library's documentation for that. It says it supports automatic gzip, so I reckon you have some mistakes in your request.

Comment: Another solution might be to manually unzip the data you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

instead of 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            MyLog.log(TAG, response.toString());
            // if is Jsonobjec     
            }

 @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
             MyLog.log(TAG, response.toString());
            // if is JsonArray    
        }
```

Or you want get response string:

```
 @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
        }
```

Comment: It is returing gzipped content instead of JSON